# Ionic Android keyboard issues

Tags: android

TextArea android  ionic4 when user touch or  type the message keyboard visbible but text area not visble 
any solution regarding this.

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar class="footer_toolbar">
      <ion-textarea class="text_Area"   placeholder="escreva aqui..." (keydown.enter)="onKeydown($event)"
        (keyup.enter)="send_User_Message(Chat_message)" [(ngModel)]="Chat_message"></ion-textarea>
       <span class="send_Icon" (click)="send_User_Message(Chat_message)">
        <img src="../../assets/icon/sendmail.png" />
      </span>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
```